# how to to print a bill (small size pages) in a AIR application

Tags: apache-flex, printing, air, invoice

I am creating an AIR application for a salon,I want to print the invoice in small pages .

How can i achieve these???  Please help me

Thanks.

Comment: Please define what "Small pages" means?  Usually I recommend folks send print data to a server, and return a PDF for printing purposes.

Comment: small page means 250*500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web sample can convert it to AIR: - Please find sample dataGrid print and how you can change it to 250*250. where as you can create custom component layout only for print view and include printing component to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import mx.printing.*;

        // Create a PrintJob instance.
        private function doPrint():void {
            var printJob:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();
            if (printJob.start() != true) 
                return;
            myDataGridPrint.height = 250;
            myDataGridPrint.width = 250;
            myDataGridPrint.dataProvider = myDataGrid.dataProvider;
            printJob.addObject(myDataGridPrint, FlexPrintJobScaleType.NONE);
            printJob.send();
        }
        ]]>

    </fx:Script>

    <mx:VBox id="myVBox">
        <mx:DataGrid id="myDataGrid" width="300">
            <mx:dataProvider>
                <fx:Object Product="Flash" Code="1000"/>
                <fx:Object Product="Flex" Code="2000"/>
                <fx:Object Product="ColdFusion" Code="3000"/>
                <fx:Object Product="JRun" Code="4000"/>
            </mx:dataProvider>
        </mx:DataGrid>
        <!--Print Data Grid-->
        <mx:DataGrid id="myDataGridPrint" visible="false" includeInLayout="false"/>
        <mx:Button id="myButton" 
                   label="Print" 
                   click="doPrint();"/>
    </mx:VBox>

</s:Application>
```

Hope this may help...